# WrongFileLengthExeption when installing Windows Azure Plugin in MyEclipse, No error when Installing into Eclipse Indigo. Suggestions?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, azure, myeclipse

I've tried installing the Windows Azure SKD+Plugin in MyEclipse. I've done it in Eclipse Indigo without a problem, but when I try to use the same link (http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse) in MyEclipse I get the following error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=com.poweredbypulse.profile-0-rb-5513151-1330619618181, phase=com.genuitec.pulse2.client.common.download.PulseCollect, operand=, action=).
Unable to retrieve

org.eclipse.update.feature,com.persistent.winazure.eclipseplugin.feature,1.6.0.201201121023
Unable to retrieve artifact; see log for more details
com.genuitech.pulse2.client.common.download.WrongFileLengthException: 9310 is not expected; should have been 5237
Unable to retrieve

osgi.bundle,com.microsoft.sqljdbc4.ui,3.0.1301.202
Unable to retrieve artifact; see log for more details
com.genuitech.pulse2.client.common.download.WrongFileLengthException: 16094 is not expected; should have been 11614

The error seems to be WrongFileLengthException, how can I correct the file length?

Answer (score 0):

Try the setup instructions for Azure and Eclipse here; http://www.windowsazure4e.org/download/

Comment: That is for Eclipse, I'm installing in MyEclipse.